# Why is ))(() not in P?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Suppose P is a set of balanced parentheses. Balanced parentheses is defined inductively and recursively as such:

1. $\lambda$ is an empty balanced parentheses
2. $\lambda\in P$
3. if $w\in P$, then $(w)\in P$.
4. if $w_1\in P$, $w_2\in P$, then $w_1w_2\in P$.

As a human, by common sense, since ))(() has a ) at front, it violates the definition of balanced parentheses.

But my question is, how to use the definition above rigorously to prove this proposition since I am so troubled by can't using both direct and contrapositive proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear from the construction that a balanced parentheses will start with a $($ or be empty. This is because they are all constructed from $\lambda$ using the rules 1, 2, 3 and 4 and none of the rules can make a parentheses start with $)$ starting from parentheses that don't start with a $)$.

This is proved inductively. Let $P_n$ be the set of all balanced parentheses after $n$ or fewer applications of the 4 rules starting from $\lambda$. So $P_0=\{\lambda\}$, $P_1=\{\lambda, ()\}$ etc. Assume that no element of $P_n$ starts with a $)$, then clearly no element of $P_{n+1}$ does. Furthermore $P_0$ contains no element starting with $)$. To finish this off, we note that every balanced parentheses must belong to $P_n$ for some $n$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show by induction that

- Number of `(`'s equals the number of `)`'s.

Your sequence violates that.

It's also easy to show by induction (and follows immediately from the above), that all generated sequences have an even length. The length of your sequence `))(()` is odd.